# Acra Android OS 11 and 12 Mac Address

Tags: android, acra

im using Acra on Android OS10, We will update soon to OS12, Will it be possible for Acra to get the MAC address from the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will it be possible for Acra to get the MAC address from the device?

No. [MAC address access has been restricted to system apps since Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids?hl=en#mac-addresses), several years ago.